# How to apply filter based on dates of an already existing database with Django Queryset

Tags: python, django

So i have the below's QuerySet output :

> <QuerySet [{'price': 12.515, 'price_date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3,
> 13, 0, 0, tzinfo=)}, {'price': 12.335, 'price_date':
> datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 14, 0, 0, tzinfo=)}, {'price': 12.37,
> 'price_date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 15, 0, 0, tzinfo=)},
> {'price': 12.35, 'price_date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 16, 0, 0,
> tzinfo=)}, {'price': 12.305, 'price_date':
> datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 17, 0, 0, tzinfo=)}...

How can i get say the price with price_date = 11-26-21 (November 26th 2021) ? Or if i want to filter by latest 30 prices?

Thanks

UPDATE 1:

When doing `Product.objects.filter(price_date="2021-11-27")`

I get the following runtime warning:

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField product.price_date received a naive
> datetime (2021-11-26 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
> warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)"
> <QuerySet []>

UPDATE 2:

When inputting '2021-09-28 08:38:13 CEST'. I get the below:

```
raise exceptions.ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['�2021-09-28 08:38:13 CEST� value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
```

Comment: I suggest reading the django documentation for the `filter()` method on a QuerySet.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an initial `QuerySet`, you can still `filter` your results.

To extract the price, use `values_list`

```
prices = qs.filter(price_date='2021-11-26').values_list('price', flat=True)
```

**Update**

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField product.price_date received a naive datetime (2021-11-26 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
> warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)" <QuerySet []>

Use `make_aware`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import make_aware

Product.objects.filter(price_date=make_aware(datetime(2021, 11, 26)))
```

Comment: Thanks man, please check my update on the original post

Answer (score 0):

You can use either datetime objects or strings inside the filter expression:

```
filter_date = datetime.now()
Product.objects.filter(price_date=filter_date)
Product.objects.filter(price_date__lte=filter_date)

# or
Product.objects.filter(price_date__lte="2021-11-27 20:00:00")
Product.objects.filter(price_date="2021-11-27")
```

For the last 30 items, you would order the query set according to the price_date reversed and then take the first 30 items.

Comment: If you want to respect time zones, then the `filter_date` should also have time zone information (see Python docs on datetime time zone support). In some cases you can ignore the warning, e.g. when you are sure that the datetimes inside your database are on the timezone which you assume when using the string "2021-11-02".

Comment: Thanks. Still not working though, could you please check my update on the original post?

Comment: You did not use a time zone inside your filter date. Try e.g. `"2021-09-28 08:38:13 CEST"` or with `"UTC"`. Please consult docs on Python datetime.

Comment: Here's what i get : 
>raise exceptions.ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['�2021-09-28 08:38:13 CEST� value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']

Comment: Ah yes, Django requires a different timezone format, like `"2016-10-03T19:00:00+0200"`. In any case, I would prefer creating Python datetime objects, see Python datetime documentation